# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre «análisis» y «cálculo»?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

En países angloparlantes el *análisis* es una rama de las matemáticas diferente del *cálculo*. Trata de los conceptos teóricos del cálculo y enfatiza demostraciones abstractas ([Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32433/are-calculus-and-real-analysis-the-same-thing), [duplicado](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318103/what-on-earth-is-the-difference-between-calculus-and-analysis)). Esta distinción no existe en países como Francia e Italia.

¿En la lengua española existe una diferencia entre *análisis* y *cálculo*?

Si es así,

- ¿es análogo a la diferencia entre los términos ingleses?
- ¿En cuáles países existe y no existe?

Comment: En la licenciatura de Matemáticas en España se usa _análisis_ y _cálculo_ de forma indistinta a efectos prácticos.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' “SO stop harming”?

Comment: Dime, @gen-z ready to perish

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' ¿Qué quiere decir “SO stop harming”?

Comment: Véase [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/209901) y [Firing Community Managers: Stack Exchange is not interested in cooperating with the community, is it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342039/209901). Es una forma de protesta ante las acciones de Stack Exchange como empresa.

Comment: "Esta distinción no existe en países como Francia e Italia." I think you've misinterpreted some comments on one of the answers on that post. It seems what you want to ask is **does *cálculo* have an analogous 'fuzzy' definition in any Spanish regions** (similar to the vague way it is used in English mathematical education to describe introductory analysis courses/material including differentiable and integral calculus as the major components), not does *análisis* exist as an extension of *cálculo*.

Comment: @ukemi That could be. If I’ve mixed it up and in fact *análisis* is the primary word and *cálculo* is the term that does/doesn’t have that formal meaning, then please enlighten me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digamos que, en teoría, desde un punto de vista histórico y formal, el término "cálculo" se refiere a toda una serie de procedimientos matemáticos que actualmente han sido absorbidos por lo que hoy en día se denomina "análisis matemático".

Cito del [*Diccionari de matemàtiques i estadística*](https://books.google.es/books/about/Diccionari_de_matem%C3%A0tiques_i_estad%C3%ADsti.html?id=LQ5yPQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) (aunque esté en catalán, no hay ninguna diferencia entre los conceptos "càlcul" en catalán y "cálculo" en castellano, ni entre "anàlisi matemàtica" en catalán y "análisis matemático" en castellano: de hecho, el propio diccionario da estas equivalencias en las respectivas entradas):

> **càlcul** *m*   Conjunt de mètodes que, aplicats a una col·lecció de símbols o nombres, permeten obtenir el resultat d'una operació o, en general, d'un problema. El càlcul constitueix el fonament de tota la matemàtica quantitativa. Limitat a l'àlgebra i a l'aritmètica fins al segle XVII, l'aparició i el desenvolupament posterior del càlcul diferencial, el càlcul integral i el càlcul de variacions feren preveure per al càlcul un abast i una capacitat de resolució gairebé absoluts, de manera que Leibniz pensà a reduir totes les ciències en una de sola sota la direcció d'un càlcul superior, síntesi de l'àlgebra i de la lògica. El càlcul ha restat absorbit pel camp més genèric de l'anàlisi matemàtica. [...]

Mi traducción:

> **càlculo** *m*   Conjunto de métodos que, aplicados a una colección de símbolos o números, permiten obtener el resultado de una operación o, en general, de un problema.  El cálculo constituye el fundamento de toda la matemática cuantitativa.  Limitado al álgebra y a la aritmética hasta el siglo XVII, la aparición y el desarrollo posterior del cálculo diferencial, el cálculo integral y el cálculo de variaciones hicieron prever para el cálculo un alcance y una capacidad de resolución casi absolutos, de manera  que Leibniz pensó en reducir todas las ciencias en una sola bajo la dirección de un cálculo superior, síntesis del álgebra y de la lógica.  El cálculo ha sido absorbido por el campo más genérico del análisis matemático.  [...]

En la entrada "anàlisi matemàtica" del mismo diccionario, podemos leer

> **anàlisi matemàtica** *f*   Part de les matemàtiques bastida sobre els conceptes bàsics de funció, límit, continuïtat, derivada i integral. És el desenvolupament modern del càlcul infinitesimal, elaborat durant els segles XVII i XVIII, que tenia com a principals problemes el de les quadratures (determinació de la longitud d'una corba i de les àrees i volums de figures) i el de la tangència (traçat de tangents a corbes i superficies). Els coneixements que s'anaren acumulant sobre aquests temes formaren els càlculs integral i diferencial, cor d'aquesta disciplina matemàtica.
>   L'anàlisi matemàtica presenta els trets distintius de l'abstracció i generalitat dels seus mètodes, característics del rigor del raonament lògic. El primer procés d'abstracció culminà durant el segle XVII, i el segon, de generalització, durant el XIX. Es conseqüència, però, de l'obra de matemàtics de totes les èpoques: es produeix tant per l'afinament gradual de nocions inexactes o incorrectes, com per la participació decisiva de matemàtics sobresortints. [...] En l'anàlisi
>   matemàtica actual es reconeixen les següents branques: funcions de variable real, funcions de variable complexa, equacions diferencials, anàlisi funcional, geometria diferencial, càlcul variacional i teoria de la mesura. [...]

Traducido al castellano, sería

> **análisis matemático** *m*    Parte de las matemáticas construida sobre los conceptos básicos de función, límite, continuidad, derivada e integral.  Es el desarrollo moderno del cálculo infinitesimal, elaborado durante los siglos XVII y XVIII, que tenía como principales problemas el de las cuadraturas (determinación de la longitud de una curva y de las áreas y volúmenes de figuras) y el de la tangencia (trazado de tangentes a curvas y superficies).  Los conocimientos que se fueron acumulando sobre estos temas formaron el cálculo integral y el cálculo diferencial, corazón de esta disciplina matemática. El análisis matemático presenta los rasgos distintivos de la abstracción y generalidad de sus métodos, característicos del rigor del razonamiento lógico.  El primer proceso de abstracción culminó durante el siglo XVII, y el segundo, de generalización, durante el XIX.  Es consecuencia, sin embargo, de la obra de matemáticos de todas las épocas: se produce tanto por el afinamiento gradual de nociones inexactas o incorrectas, como por la participación decisiva de matemáticos sobresalientes.  [...] En el análisis matemático actual se reconocen las siguientes ramas: funciones de variable real, funciones de variable compleja, ecuaciones diferenciales, análisis funcional, geometría diferencial, cálculo de variaciones y teoría de la medida.  [...]

En teoría es así. Ahora bien, según mi experiencia, en la práctica, "análisis" y "cálculo" se usan frecuentemente como sinónimos, incluso en títulos de libros, aunque cada vez se utiliza más la terminología más moderna de "análisis matemático". El propio diccionario que he citado tiene una de sus primeras páginas titulada "Arbre de camp" ("árbol de campo"), en la cual se da un esquema de clasificación de temas y subtemas abarcados por el libro. Los temas que aparecen, traducidos al castellano, son los siguientes:

- Términos generales
- Aritmética
- Álgebra
- Geometría
- Topología
- Cálculo
- Matemática discreta
- Probabilidad
- Estadística

No me consta que existan diferencias regionales en este aspecto. Por poner algún ejemplo, tengo en casa una traducción de Rodolfo Piña García del libro *Introduction to Real Analysis* de Robert G. Bartle, publicada por la Editorial Limusa (México) en 1984. Es un libro en el que he constatado algunas diferencias en el vocabulario utilizado para ciertos conceptos matemáticos respecto al que se usa en España. Su título es *Introducción al Análisis Matemático de una Variable* (escrito así, con todas estas mayúsculas). Pero de libros del mismo ámbito, podemos encontrar, por ejemplo, este [*Cálculo*](https://books.google.es/books/about/C%C3%A1lculo_v2.html?id=nYJ6xQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) de Serge Lang, publicado por el Fondo Educativo Interamericano.

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo. Como comenté en la pregunta, en la Licenciatura de Matemáticas siempre lo vi usar de forma indistinta.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming':  La traducción del libro de Bartle que he mencionado la usábamos en mi primer año de universidad (iba a decir en la prehistoria) y nos hacía a todos mucha gracia por el vocabulario que, obviamente, el profesor no utilizaba (entre otras cosas, porque hablaba en catalán). Sobretodo, el uso de "vecindades" en lugar de "entornos" nos hacía reír. Pero en la utilización de los términos "análisis" y "cálculo" (en la práctica frecuentemente como sinónimos) nunca he encontrado diferencias regionales.

Comment: Otro libro que utilizábamos en la misma asignatura era la traducción del ruso hecha por el Departamento Técnico de Montaner y Simón, S.A., del libro *DIFERENTSIALNOYE I INTEGRALNOYE ISCHISLENIE* (así es como lo escriben) de N. Piskunov, con título traducido como *Cálculo diferencial e integral* (no es "cálculo" a secas, pero podría titularse "Cálculo" y a nadie le extrañaría).

Comment: Al hilo de esta publicación y alguna otra, he preguntado en Meta [¿Es necesario mostrar el texto original que citamos si no está escrito en inglés o castellano?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4332/1674), por si quieres echarle una ojeada.

Comment: También disfruté de las traducciones hechas en México, en general recuerdo que la terminología era bastante consistente en comparación con la usada en libros escritos en España